# Допустимые символы в именах атрибутов/тегов

Tags: html, css

```
 ng:view {
display: block;
height:100px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

ng-include {
display: block;height:100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
ng_inc{display: block;height:100px;
border: 1px solid orange;}

    <ng:view>view</ng:view>
    <ng-include>include</ng-include> 
    <ng_inc>inc</ng_inc>
```

Какие символы допустимы в названиях тегов/атрибутов и как их стилизировать через CSS?
Работает только `ng_inc` ,`ng-include` не работает толково(только CSS а содержимое не показывает),`ng:view` вообще не срабатывает CSS -правило.

Comment: Вроде тего/атрибуты могут быть только такими, как названия в js, не?

Comment: Глядя на ваш код, вам необходимо хотя бы сначала открыть Википедию и почитать что такое html и css.

Comment: michael судя по вопросу http://hashcode.ru/questions/236465/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8-css3-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-css-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-css3 вам нужно также почитать о них

Comment: @SverxnovA, вы правила HTML сами придумали?

Comment: Видимо народ не слышал о пользовательских HTML5 атрибутах....

Comment: @SverxnovA, Это видимо вы "слышали звон, да не знаете где он". Если и брать [упоминания о пользовательских атрибутах](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute), то речь идете в частности об атрибуте **data-***

Comment: data-* Это только обеcпечивание валидности...атрибут может быть любым.

Comment: @SverxnovA, тогда буду признателен, если ткнёте меня носом туда, где это описано в официальной документации. Кто ж сказал, что я не могу ошибаться?

Comment: <p id="foo" atr="val"></p>
console.log(document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('atr'))

Comment: @SverxnovA, так это другая тема, а не то, что у вас в опросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу:

```
<ng:view>view</ng:view>
```

Тут идет смесь xml и html. С точки зрения xml вы задали namespace ng. В css его также необходимо объявлять:

```
@namespace ng url(http://site.com/namespace);
```

и тогда правило будет выглядеть так:

```
ng|view {
  display: block;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

С точки зрения html двоеточие используется для псевдоклассов. Чтоб двоеточие воспринималось как часть имени тэга, правило должно выглядеть так:

```
ng\:view {
  display: block;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Т.е. эскейпим двоеточие.

Чтобы CSS правила для x(ht)ml и html работали совместно (читай "хоть что-то где-нибудь да сработало"), надо просто использовать оба селектора для правила через запятую. Хотя и сомневаюсь, что такие танцы необходимы...

Comment: Опять та самая проблема -содержимое тега не отображается.Ответ более -менее понравился, кроме фраз, которые можно индентифицировать как оскорбление....
"Сомневаюсь, впрочем, что вы хотели указать namespace, просто видимо символы на клавиатуре для идентификаторов кончаются, да? =)"
Нет.

Comment: это не оскорбление, просто подозрение, что используете не по назначению namespace. шутка. не обращайте внимание. удалил.

Comment: по поводу не отображается содержимое - не понял. у меня отображается http://jsfiddle.net/3PrgJ/ тестил в хроме.

Comment: Все я понял. Это проблема в оброботке AngularJs.Все работает.Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

забудьте это как страшный сон :)

имхо, пользовательские теги работают для обратной совместимости: HTML5 развивается, появятся новые теги, и чтобы нынешние (а к тому времени устаревшие) браузеры смогли их поддерживать и введена возможность объявлять пользовательские элементы.

[W3C настоятельно не рекомендует](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#elements) их использовать:

> Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values that are not permitted by this specification or other applicable specifications, as doing so makes it significantly harder for the language to be extended in the future.

что касается формата имени тега, не могу сказать, почему не работает вариант с "-". если я правильно понимаю, то [согласно спецификации](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html#dfn-custom-element) должен работать:

> The custom element type identifies a custom element interface and is a sequence of alphanumeric ASCII characters that must match the [NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName) production and contain a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character. The custom element type must not be one of the following values:
>
> - annotation-xml color-profile
> - font-face font-face-src font-face-uri
> - font-face-format font-face-name
> - missing-glyph